# how to get node path in cq5 while building a query?

Tags: aem, query-builder

How to get node path in CQ5 while building a query?

I have tried the below code, but its not working

```
path=/data/locations/
type=stb:Location
property_1=jcr:path
property_1.value=/data/locations/berlin 
p.hits=full
```

So, Please suggest the better way to query in AEM?

Please note that there is no property called path in node

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve? In general, all the queries return a list of nodes which satisfies the query. If you can explain the requirement a bit more people might be able to help you with a better solution.

Comment: We are getting **/data/locations/berlin** as an input. We have to fetch the details of the node which is present in  **/data/locations/berlin** location.

Comment: If you already have the node path, then you get the details of the node using either session.getNode(path) or resourceResolver.getResource(path).adaptTo(Node.class). You don't need a query for that

Comment: Thanks buddy, It works..